# IIlegalStateException: System service not available to activities before onCreate() [ProgressDialog]

Tags: android

I am starting a activity(Activity2) from another activity(Activity1). And I am showing a progress dialog in public method of Activity1. When I call this method from Activity2 then an exception occurs.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity{

   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

   public Activity1(){
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity1);           
   }

   public void showDialog(){
      progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this,
                "Please Wait");
      progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.DialogStyle);
      progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
      progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
   }

   //On Clicking a button this method gets called
   private void nextActivity(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity{
   private Activity1 activity1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity2);  
      activity1 = new Activity1();
      activity1.showDialog();         
   }
}
```

After call from Activity2 to Activity1's showDialog() method it gives exception on following line of showDialog() method:

> progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this,
>                       "Please Wait");

I also tried making object of ProgressDialog as static but that didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way of accessing the method in another `Activity`.

The best approach is to add a `Base Activity` and move your showDialog code there. You can add all your common `Activity` codes inside the `Base Activity`

Create a Base Activity like this

```
  public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
      private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this,
            "Please Wait");
   }

      public void showDialog(){
       progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.DialogStyle);
       progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
       progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
       progressDialog.show();
  }
```

Now you can extends the BaseActivity from all the required Activities like this and call the showDialog() method when required.

```
   public Activity2 extends BaseActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity2);
           // show the progress dialog
           showDialog();         
       }
   }
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can resolve this error without moving a method into another activity ??? Because what if I am doing some actions in showDialog() method which are related to context of Activity1 and can not be done in another activity.

Comment: You can override showDialog in Activity1 if it does any different action.